# Best approach to INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

What would you say is an effective and perhaps a robust approach to doing

> INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Some has argued "REPLACE is bad because it first deletes the duplicate, then inserts a replacement.  INSERT/ON DUPLICATE first checks then does an update if it finds a match.  This is a big difference."

Guys what do you think? point us on the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY for 8 years already - and never had any issues with it.
I call it "transactions for poor people" among my friends. 
Of course it's a joke, but the important point this - this operation is ***atomic***

Answer (score 1):

Use REPLACE only if you need a newly generated surrogate key, imo. Otherwise, on duplicate gives you more granular control of value changes and is more explicit.